# AngularJS - Assign DIV a Width Based on values in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class, ng-style

I have a simple ng-repeat that throws out a bunch of data:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData" class="myClass">
    {{data.Name}}
    {{data.Age}}
</div>
```

Which will throw out something like:

```
Pete
25
Adam
43
Lewis
19
```

How can i add a CSS property to my DIV based on the value in `{{data.Age}}`

So, if the age is 25, my DIV should have width of 25%.

I've tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData" ng-style="{width: data.Age +'%'}">
    {{data.Name}}
    {{data.Age}}
</div>
```

Which fails

Update with Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HdyDByoZ2aR1Ajsf2eFQ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regular style property and write in the width:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData" style="width: {{data.Age}}%;">
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HdyDByoZ2aR1Ajsf2eFQ?p=preview didnt work.

Comment: @OamPsy -- The element is getting the style applied, it's just not having the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely work :

```
<div ng-repeat="data in myData" ng-style="{width: data.Age+'%'}">
```

Example code : [http://plnkr.co/edit/7aPwPnRvjtRY9H1aPNPG](http://plnkr.co/edit/7aPwPnRvjtRY9H1aPNPG?p=preview)